# Why array_diff gives error?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to figure out for the last one hour why I get error 500 when I run the following code with a simple array_diff function.

```
  <?php 
    $array1 = array( [0] => "2014-12-11 14.27.23.jpg" [1] => "2014-12-11 14.27.23.jpg" ); // array to compare from (dropbox folder)
    $array2 = array([0] => "2014-12-11 14.27.23.jpg" ); // array to compare against (local folder)
    $result = array_diff($array1, $array2); // iterate on this array and download these pics
    print_r($result);
   ?>
```

Any kind of enlightenment is much appreciated.

Thanks 
D.

Comment: Your array syntax is incorrect, and looks like it was copied from a `print_r()` dump. remove the `[]` on the array indices, or better, remove the indices entirely.

Comment: `array("2014-12-11 14.27.23.jpg");` or if you must specify the index `array(0 => "2014-12-11 14.27.23.jpg");` but that's uncommon for a numeric array.

Comment: Yes it was copied indeed from a print_r only for test purposes. I didn't know that this affects the array_diff() function.

Comment: Array don't get initialized as you write: it should be `$array1 = array( "2014-12-11 14.27.23.jpg", "2014-12-11 14.27.23.jpg" ); `

Comment: Always when developing code, enable PHP's display_errors. At the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  The 500 error would meanwhile be more detailed in the error log.

Comment: It doesn't just affect `array_diff()`, it is not parseable as PHP in general.  The indices can't be bracketed inside an `array()` declaration.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot Michael Berkowski.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
<?php 
 $array1 = array("2014-12-11 14.27.23.jpg","2014-12-11 14.27.23.jpg" ); 
$array2 = array("2014-12-11 14.27.23.jpg" ); 
    $result = array_diff($array1, $array2); 
    print_r($result);
   ?>
```

This difference of array is empty.If you use $result = (array_diff_key($array1, $array2)); meants the result is Array ( [1] => 2014-12-11 14.27.23.jpg ).